# projective modules over a finite algebra is itself

Tags: linear-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional (graded) associative algebra over $k$. Suppose $M$ is a projective left $A$-module with the same dimension of $A$ over $k$. How to prove that the $A$-module $M$ is isomorphic to $A$ up to a suspension?

Comment: This is not true. Let A be $k\times k$ concentrated in degree zero, let I be the ideal of A generated by (1,0), and let M be the direct sum of two copies of I.

Comment: You can fix this by adding hypotheses... For example, if the algebra is graded in non-negative degrees and connected (that is, its zero component is of dimension one) then the conclusion holds.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez You are right! I do need A to be graded in non-negative degrees and connected. Then how does the conclusion follows?

Comment: In that case the algebra is indecomposable as a left module, so there is exactly one isomorphism class of indecomposable projective.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks! You are right. I see that's where I need to use the structure theorem of indecomposable modules.

Comment: Write an answer with the detailed argument!